# Failed to read Docker Secret File using path defined in DB_PASS_FILE env variable

Tags: docker

I am setting up wikijs, and when I do "docker logs wiki" in the terminal, I get following error.

> Loading configuration from /wiki/config.yml... OK
> DB_PASS_FILE is defined. Will use secret from file.
>
> > > Failed to read Docker Secret File using path defined in DB_PASS_FILE env variable!
> > > EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
> > > Loading configuration from /wiki/config.yml... OK
> > > DB_PASS_FILE is defined. Will use secret from file.

I am trying to set up HTTPS for wikijs. Thank you in advance.